# Two lists in navbar using 'navbar-right', displays second list first?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

In Bootstrap 3 I'm trying to create a navbar which will have to `ul`, both of which will align to the right. But when I add `navbar-right` to both `ul`'s, they both align to the right, but the second `ul` in the markup displays first? What do I need to do to get them to display in the proper sequence?

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#about">Register</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Link to Codeply: https://www.codeply.com/go/LibLIdo8NW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write the `ul` for Register and Login first that will solve your issue.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#about">Register</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Updated [link](https://www.codeply.com/go/FlxCGEsGHK) to your demo

Update:

The class navbar-right has the property `float: right!important;` which pushes the first element to the right most of the screen.
Overriding this property would be another hack :)

Comment: Thanks, I did try that. But it feels a bit like a hack. Was just curious if there was another way.

Answer (score 0):

This is the right process. 
Check [this link](https://fiddle.jshell.net/rwyt1jar/2/).
In order to have your desired result you just have to switch the `ul`'s for these elements.

Answer (score 0):

Take navbar-right class to container for both UL's.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
            <li><a href="#about">Register</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Login</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="text-center">
        <h1>Bootstrap starter template</h1>
        <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.<br> All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```